# Потеря кодировки сайта через WebClient

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

Делаю запрос на серверы гугл и получаю вместо русского языка крокозябру, менял кодировки не помогло, может у гугла на поисковик какая нибудь хитрая кодировка стоит.
Класс для отправки запроса:

```
public static class MyWebRequest
{
    public static string Get(string url, Dictionary<string, string> QueryParameters = null, Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        using var webClient = new WebClient();
        if (encoding != null)
        {
            webClient.Encoding = encoding;
        }
        if (QueryParameters != null && QueryParameters.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (var queryParameter in QueryParameters)
            {
                webClient.QueryString.Add(queryParameter.Key, queryParameter.Value);
            }
        }
        return webClient.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

Сам запрос:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var result = MyWebRequest.Get("https://www.google.com/search",
                new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["q"] = textBoxSearch.Text.Replace(' ', '+')}, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
```

Сам сайт гугла говорит что у него в UTF-8 мол поисковая страница стоит. В чем может быть проблема?
П.С. переписал запрос на HttpClient но крокозябры остались

```
public static string Get(string url, Dictionary<string, string> QueryParameters = null)
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;
    if (QueryParameters != null && QueryParameters.Count != 0)
    {
        response = client.GetAsync($"{url}?{QueryParameters.Select(s => $"{s.Key}={s.Value}").Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}&{b}")}");
    }
    else
    {
        response = client.GetAsync(url);
    }
    return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Почитайте документацию про `WebClient`, поймете, что он является устаревшим компонентом в языке C#.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ переписал на  public static string Get(string url, Dictionary<string, string> QueryParameters = null)
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> response;
            if (QueryParameters != null && QueryParameters.Count != 0)
            {
                response = client.GetAsync($"{url}?{QueryParameters.Select(s => $"{s.Key}={s.Value}").Aggregate((a, b) => $"{a}&{b}")}");
            }
            else
            {
                response = client.GetAsync(url);
            }
            return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

Comment: Очень странный код выше, прям очень странный. А по вопросу, если вас смущают `class="gTMtLb fp-nh"`, то это защита от тех, кто хочет парсить данные, а не проблемы с кодировкой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ код в нормальном форматировании добавил к вопросу, меня смущает не название классов, а смущает {A1 A2 A3 A4 - &#1055;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082; &#1074; Google} Инглишь он нормально выводит, а где русский крокозябры

Comment: `код в нормальном форматировании` - так меня не это удивляет, а то, что вы так криво работаете с асинхронность, используя непойми зачем `.Result`, убивая тем самым всю асинхронность, нельзя так.. `а смущает` - вы пробовали это выводить на экран? Если да и там тож самое, то `WebUtility.HtmlDecode("A1 A2 A3 A4 - &#1055;&#1086;&#1080;&#1089;&#1082; &#1074; Google")` вам в помощь)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ WebUtility.HtmlDecode помогло, спасибо. А на счет асинхронности я с ней париться не хочу пока не появится надобность в этом

Comment: Она уже у вас появилась. Ваш код выше тупо повесит интерфейс (если это WinForms или WPF) на момент получения данных от сервера. Нравятся зависания интерфейса, дергание, фризы, ну... Дело ваше, а я лучше напишу не `string`, а `async Task<string>` и не `response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`, а `var html = await client.GetStringAsync(..);`...

Comment: Этими `.Result` можно вообще намертво повесить приложение. sync-over-async - яд, не травите свое приложение, используйте `async/await`.

Comment: @aepot даже если я буду тащить async/await до куда могу из вызовов, то в конце мне все равно придется вызвать Result чтобы получить результат ибо на обработчик кнопки я уже не могу натянуть async. я бы понял смысл Task в том случае если бы у него был event окончания на который можно было бы подписаться, но такое я увы не нашел

Comment: @eapot В интернете много примеров где они тащат await/async и заканчивают главным методом async main. Да даже в ответе ниже выводят в консоль у которой главный метод async. Но у меня обработчик кнопки WPF без async следовательно написав await я получаю ошибку которая решается с помощью вызова result.

Comment: Вы уверены, что Microsoft просто так придумал эту бесполезную хрень, которая не работает, по вашему мнению? `на обработчик кнопки я уже не могу натянуть async` почему же, вы пробовали? async void обработчики кнопок - вполне себе нормальное явление. Вот только один нюанс - в WPF вообще не должно быть обработчиков кнопок. Короч, async не меняет сигнатуру метода, а следовательно его можно добавлять и удалять где угодно. Единственное ограничение, Task в возвращаемом типе не поставить, но в обработчике это и не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делаете много лишних телодвижений.

```
public static class MyWebRequest
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All })
    { 
        DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20
    };

    public static async Task<string> GetAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string> queryParameters = null)
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(url);
        if (queryParameters?.Count > 0)
        {
            builder.Query = await new FormUrlEncodedContent(queryParameters).ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return await client.GetStringAsync(builder.Uri);
    }
}
```

Проверяю, использую NuGet пакет **HtmlAgilityPack**.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var html = await MyWebRequest.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/search", new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["q"] = "get запрос C#" });
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var title = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(title);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
get запрос C# - Поиск в Google
```

Кодировки типа ANSI и UTF-8 определяются автоматически. А если зарегать провайдер `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` то и Win1251 скушает само.

---

Асинхронный обработчик кнопки в WPF выглядел бы так.

```
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.IsEnabled = false; // защита от повторного нажатия, так как
                           // если не морозить UI, теперь он работает во время выполнения кода.
                           // в этом и есть смысл асинхронности здесь

    var html = await MyWebRequest.GetAsync("https://www.google.com/search", new Dictionary<string, string>() { ["q"] = "get запрос C#" });
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var title = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title").InnerText);
    Debug.WriteLine(title);

    btn.IsEnabled = true;
}
```